# Parallels: Make sure VMs never start automatically at program startup

Tags: parallels-desktop

If I quit Parallels when there are virtual machines running, then these machines are automatically started the next time I start Parallels.

Is there any way to make sure that Parallels *never* automatically start any VM at startup?

I have already set the "Start Automatically" setting set to "Never" for all my VMs. (Its under "Virtual Machine > Configure...", and then "Options > Startup and Shutdown"). But this is not helping.

I'm using Parallels Desktop 9 (Build 9.0.24251).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please enable `On Quit: ☑ Disable Resume for Parallel Desktop` in Parallels Desktop -> Preferences -> General

[image: Parallels Preferences]

Comment: It seems that this option is no longer available anymore. Do you know a new way?